# From where comes extra html for Spree login page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

This is _login.html.erb partial from Spree github page:

```
<%= form_for Spree::User.new, as: :spree_user, url: spree.create_new_session_path do |f| %>
  <fieldset id="password-credentials">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', tabindex: 1, placeholder: Spree.t(:email) %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', tabindex: 2, placeholder: Spree.t(:password) %>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%= f.label :remember_me, Spree.t(:remember_me) %>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit Spree.t(:login), class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block', tabindex: 3 %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

but in reality when go to that page that form is built-in in panel with heading "Login as Existing customer".

[image]

from where it comes?

[image]

Comment: Check the rails' log. You'll see every partial and layout it renders, you'll see a line showing your `_login` partial and there must be more renders, one of them will point you on the file. Anyway, you didn't specify this, but are you using spree_bootstrap_frontend gem? if so, check this file https://github.com/Purepoint/spree_bootstrap_frontend/blob/490c13e5669edab6f1631ef74b59f975a1b523f5/spree_auth_devise_bootstrap/lib/views/frontend/spree/user_sessions/new.html.erb

Comment: Thanks a lot! Anyway, how I'm using spree_bootstrap_frontend gem? I have never installed it. Does any of these includes it? gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.7'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.4' because these are only gems I've installed

Comment: Check your Gemfile.lock, if you have that gem it will show you what gem depends on it.

Comment: @synopsa check http://railscasts.com/episodes/298-getting-started-with-spree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comes from a different template, located here: https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/master/app/views/spree/user_sessions/new.html.erb.

If you search Spree's code for the sentence 'Login as Existing Customer', you'll see it's present in their [locales](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/4cc2c2967352d3fe7652bd873e492c074ffcc3da/core/config/locales/en.yml) with the key `login_as_existing`.

A little more digging, and I found the key on line five of the template linked above (as well as [a couple of other locations](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/search?q=login_as_existing&unscoped_q=login_as_existing)). You can replace this in the same way you have the login form, or adjust the locale if you'd prefer different terminology. And a final third option, you can use Spree's [deface overrides](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/deface_overrides_tutorial.html).

Tricky to track down these views sometimes, though search the main repo and any of the included extensions and you should be able to track anything down :)